# upload images/files to AWS S3 via Laravel 5.1, unfortunately the images are corrupted

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

How i've attempted to upload the images to S3 through Laravel 5.1 while the images received in S3 are believed to be corrupted as the images below.

[images in S3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nr8HT.jpg)

**Step 1** : Using Composer

1. composer require aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel:~3.0
2. open config from the vendor of laravel 5.1

> `'region' => env('AWS_REGION', 'my region'),
>       'version' => 'latest',
>       'ua_append' => [
>           'L5MOD/' . AwsServiceProvider::VERSION,
>       ],
>       'credentials' => [
>           'key'    => 'enter your code',
>           'secret' => 'enter your code'
>       ],
>       'scheme' => 'http'`

**Step 2**

1. add these lines provider and alias for class activation in config/app.php

> `Providers
>   'Aws\Laravel\AwsServiceProvider',
>   Alias
>   'AWS' => 'Aws\Laravel\AwsFacade'`

**Step 3**

1. set up the controller

   ```
   namespace App\Http\Controllers;

   use Illuminate\Http\Request;
   use App\Http\Requests;
   use \Auth, \Redirect, \Validator, \Input, \Session, \Response;
   use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
   use App\Http\Requests\PhotoRequest;
   use App\Photo;
   use \Image;
   use \File;

   use AWS;

   class PhotoController extends Controller
   {
   protected   $photo;
   public function __construct(Photo $photo) {
           $this->photo = $photo;
       }   

   public function index()
   {
           $p = Photo::all();
           return view('photo.index')
               ->with('photos',$p);

   }

   public function create()
   {
           return view('photo.create')->with('photos',$this->_data);
   }


   /**
    * Store a newly created resource in storage.
    *
    * @return Response
    */
   public function store(PhotoRequest $request)
   {

        $input = Input::all();

           if ($this->photo->isValid($input)) {
               $img = $request->file('file');

               $mime = $input['file']->getMimeType();
               $fileName = time() . "." . strtolower($input['file']->getClientOriginalExtension());

               $image = Image::make(file_get_contents($img->getRealPath()));
               $this->upload_s3($image, $fileName, $mime, "resource/Original");
               $image->resize(400, 300);
               $this->upload_s3($image, $fileName, $mime, "resource/Thumbnail");

               Photo::create([
                   'title' => Input::get('title'),
                   'file' => $fileName,
               ]);

               Session::flash('exito', $image);
               return Redirect::route('photo.index');
           } else {
               Session::flash('error', 'Failed');
               return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($this->photo->messages);
           }
   }  
       private function upload_s3($image, $fileName, $mime, $folder) {
           $s3 = AWS::createClient('s3');

           try{
                $s3->putObject(array(
                   'Bucket'      => 'mybucket',
                   'Key'         => "{$folder}/{$fileName}",
                   'Body'        => "$image",
                   'ContentType' => $mime,
                   'ACL'         => 'public-read',


               ));   
            } catch(S3Exception $e){
               echo $e->getAwsErrorCode() . "\n";
               // The bucket couldn't be created
               echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
            }

       }

       private $_data = array();
       private $path = "img/upload/";
   ```

   }

**Step 4**

1. Set up the View in Laravel 5.1 for UI

   ```
   @extends('app')
   @section('content')

   <h1>Create:</h1>
   {!! Form::open(array('url' => 'photo/store', 'files' => true)) !!}

       <div class="form-group">
         <label for="title">Title</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title" placeholder="Photo Title">
          <span class="help-block color-red">{!! $errors->first('title') !!}</span>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
         <label for="file">File</label>
         <input type="file" class="form-control" id="file" name="file">
          <span class="help-block color-red">{!! $errors->first('file') !!}</span>
       </div>
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Create</button>
   {!! Form::close() !!}
   @endsection
   ```

Please advise me what've I left and what should I look for?, this is because i have googled many solutions and it is still not working for me even I followed the several steps proposed by some other developers.Hence, it is either i am not comprehend enough with the functions or my attempts do not have a suitable solution?

Comment: Can you include the used Imports in your controller, we can't see what `Image` is in this example.

Comment: alright sure. sorry about that

Comment: @Luceos I have included, anyway just click at the image link to see the result

Comment: can you `dd($img->getRealPath(), file_get_contents($img->getRealPath()))` in the code to see what the contents of the file is and where the file is located according to your app

Comment: okay, wait a moment.

Comment: @Luceos It shows image code.

Comment: What package supplied the Image facade?

Comment: @Luceos i am using image intervention package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok now that we are aware you are using Intervention, use the appropriate way of instantiating the Image object with `make`:

```
$image = Image::make($input['file']);
```

According to the documentation the `make()` method can take a string, a path but also an UploadedFile object.

Now safely write the data to S3:

```
         $s3->putObject(array(
            'Bucket'      => 'mybucket',
            'Key'         => "{$folder}/{$fileName}",
            'Body'        => (string) $image->encode(),
            'ContentType' => $mime,
            'ACL'         => 'public-read',
        ));
```

By the way, why not use the native S3 adapter for the filesystems Laravel has? https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/filesystem#driver-prerequisites

Comment: I have used this 
$image = Image::make($input['file']);
                $this->upload_s3($image, $fileName, $mime, "resource/Original");

Comment: The result still the same, image still corrupted.

Comment: hm, i guess encoding is still required and your casting to string might be more obvious, see updated answer

Comment: You just saved my life. Thank alot. can you explain a little bit on encoding part?? Yes, I am still exploring" By the way, why not use the native S3 adapter for the filesystems Laravel has? https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/filesystem#driver-prerequisites"

Comment: Happy it worked. Not completely sure, but the encoding part is one of three ways to output the image. It might be the case that the image without outputting is saved in raw. Also if you delve deeper into that S3 api, you might notice the option of sending a stream, that might also be handy if you want to use a more promise based upload.